# AJAX call returns false when I expect true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm doing an ajax call in a code igniter application. The JS code is the following:

```
function removeGuest(guestID)
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this guest and his preferences?"))
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/event/ajax_delete_guest",
            data: { guestID: guestID },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This gets send to my controller:

```
public function ajax_delete_guest()
{
    if($this->input->post('guestID'))
    {
        $guestID = $this->input->post('guestID');
        if($this->events_model->delete_guest($guestID))
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(TRUE); 
        }
        else
        {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(FALSE);            
        }
    }
}
```

and my model:

```
public function delete_guest($guestID)
{
    $tables = array('event_guest', 'event_guest_prefs', 'event_guest_hotel');
    $this->db->where('guestID', $guestID);
    if($this->db->delete($tables))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

When removing a guest in the DB, it returns `false` in the `console.log()`. However, I'm fairly sure I'm making it return `true` when the deletion is successful. Anyone have any idea? I'm breaking my head over this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
public function delete_guest($guestID)
{
    $tables = array('event_guest_prefs', 'event_guest_hotel');
    $this->db->where('guestID', $guestID);
    if($this->db->delete('event_guest'))
    {
        $this->db->where('guestID', $guestID)->delete($tables);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Because the `prefs` and `hotel` tables aren't necessarily containing data for the $guestID, the original check returned false. The `_guest` table always contains data though, so I just check on that now and if it succeeds, I continue to delete the other tables. 
    }

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding die()?I once had the same problem and this solved it.

```
   if($this->events_model->delete_guest($guestID))
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(TRUE);
        die(); 
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(FALSE);            
        die();
    }
```

Comment: I solved it by changing my model around. I will post a solution in a minute.